# How to use PostScript for to plot the sum of cos(n*x) for n=0 to n=100?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, pst-plot

I want to plot the function `f(x)` which is the sum of `cos(n*x)` for `n=0` to `n=100`. The domain is from `0` to `2π`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psplot[plotpoints=100]{0}{TwoPi}{%
    /k 0 def
    /out 0 def      
    0 1 10
    {
        x k mul RadtoDeg cos out add /out ED
        k 1 add /k ED
    } for
    out
  }  
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output seems wrong as follows.

[image]

How to use the PostScript `for` here?

Comment: there is an exact formula for this sum, it is `1/2` + half of the Dirichlet kernel, hence: `1/2+\sin(100.5 x)/(2\sin(0.5 x))`.

Comment: @jfbu: OK. But I am learning how to use `for` in this question. :-)

Comment: ah yes, then why not something fun like `sin(nx)/log n` and the same with `cos(nx)/log n` :)

Comment: @jfbu: Because `n=0` is dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-7)(7,7)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-7)(7,7)
\psplot[plotpoints=5000,linewidth=0.2pt]{0}{TwoPi}{%
    /out 0 def      
    0 1 100
    { % loop variable is on the stack
        x mul RadtoDeg cos out add /out ED
    } for
    out
  }  
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the same with

```
\psplot[plotpoints=5000,plotstyle=dots,dotscale=0.4]{0}{TwoPi}{%
```

[image]